# Drag and drop image to canvas not working when combining fabric.js and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, drag-and-drop, fabricjs

I'm trying to set up a fabric.js canvas so that users can drag and drop image files from their system onto the canvas. In searching for a way to do that, I found [this pen](https://codepen.io/dizzyluo/pen/LZbzYv), which works okay as it, but I'm also using jQuery, and I like to create my main variables/functions at the beginning of the document and call them as needed later on.

When I reorganize the code to match my setup, the drop function stops working. [Here's a pen](https://codepen.io/Nikki0417/pen/aEWJVe?editors=0001) ([or a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gesturepoke/nej1cpzm/), if you prefer) that mimics the setup I want to use.

Here's the drop function from the pen I'm basing this on:

```
var canvas_container = document.getElementById('canvas-container');
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas_container.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
            console.log("DROP");
            e = e || window.event;
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            var dt = e.dataTransfer;
            var files = dt.files;
            for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                var reader = new FileReader();

                //attach event handlers here...
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.src = e.target.result;
                    var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
                        left: 100,
                        top: 100,
                    });
                    canvas.add(imgInstance);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }

            return false;
        });
```

And the setup I'd like to use:

```
var $main = $('#content'), 
  canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
    width: 400,
    height: 550
  }),
dropImage = function (e) {
    var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer,
        files = dt.files;
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("Drop started");
    $('.refs').removeClass('highlight');
    canvas.remove(introTxt);

    //Loop through files
    for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i],
          reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = loadReader(e);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    function loadReader(e) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = e.target.result;
        var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
          left: 100,
          top: 100
        });
        canvas.add(imgInstance);
        console.log('Images found');
    }
    console.log('Drop done');
  };
  $main.on('drop', dropImage);
```

The "Drop done" text is logged on the console, but no image actually appears on the canvas. I'm completely stumped as to why this isn't working.

Also, this will be part of a Photoshop extension, and Adobe extensions run on Chromium. So, this only needs to work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your drop handler you need to do

```
reader.onload = loadReader;
```

And add image to canvas on image onload event

```
function loadReader(event) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = event.target.result;
  img.onload = function(){
    var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
      left: 100,
      top: 100
    });
    canvas.add(imgInstance);
  }
}
```

Here is updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nej1cpzm/1/)

Comment: I felt like I was only missing one or two things but couldn't figure out what they might be. Thank you. This worked perfectly.